# How can I quickly count occurrences of a string on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given a local url, how can I quickly count number of times the string `abc` on the page using JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Example:

For the given URL: [American Broadcasting Company (ABC) [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Broadcasting_Company), how many times does `ABC` (case insensitive) occur on this page?

Answer:

- 795 (counting HTML tags)
- 455 (counting only visible text)

What javascript and/or jQuery yields similar results?

Comment: Are you planning on counting ascii words only?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in the conole or in javascript on the page:

```
$("*").html().match(/abc/gi).length
```

This will get you just text nodes on the page*:

```
var count = 0;
$("body").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).each(function () { var match = this.wholeText.match(/abc/gi); if (match) count += match.length; });
```

- Only issue I see is that javascript code between  tags, appears as a text node, so this also searches through the javascript if your script tags are contained within your  tag.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. I loaded (for example) `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Broadcasting_Company` and ran this in the console and it worked! (795, if you were curious). Though it'd be cool to only find results that are actually visible on the page (455 results).

Comment: What if there is a class name called `abc`?

Comment: @DavidSherret, interesting. That same call returns 451 for me. Not a problem with your query, more curious about how Wikipedia changes content based on users.

Answer (score 2):

So try the steps bellow:

1) Gives you the whole text on the page.

```
var temp = $('body').text();
```

2) the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string rather than just find the first occurrence

```
var count = temp.match(/abc/g);
alert(count);
alert(count.length);
```

**Example here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/a0fkqej0/

Hope it helps!

Comment: This got me pretty darn close to 455 on the ABC wiki page. The following results in 465: `$('html').text().match(/ABC/g).length`